# Expanding Drive Space in VMware for Linux use

Tags: linux, vmware

I use Ubuntu Linux to develop applications, but usually have a Linux admin setup the final environment.  I have a Linux box (via VMWare) that houses our application and Docker containers.  That works and is great.

We need to now expand the main drive / volume to be over 10 TB.  Originally, for some reason they made the original drive only 1 TB.  Now we have to make it larger.

The server team (via VMware) added for disk space to the VM (500gb) and I was able via some tutorials able to get that 500gb added to the drive via fdisk.

Great!, now they added 10 TB of space to the server.  I can see the space but when I use fdisk i get that it can't partition space larger than 2 TB.

I read online that I can use gdisk or something like that.  My questions are:

1) How can I get this 10 TB of space added to the server? and

2) If I set up this partition using something other than fdisk, can i later expand my main drive with this space since it wasn't setup in fdisk?

Comment: _Cedric_, do you have Ubuntu Server, or Ubuntu Desktop? Which version number? If it's Desktop, there's a GUI tool _gparted_ which may be helpful; if server, try _gdisk_ http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/gdisk.8.html . Please click [edit] and add that useful info into the original question. Please don't just click [Add Comment], for comments can pile up and scroll off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2TB limit you're seeing comes from the (ancient, circa 1983) DOS MBR partition table format. You are limited to 2³² sectors, which with 512-byte sectors is where 2TiB comes from. `fdisk` often supports only DOS MBR.

The solution to this is to use a newer partition table format, GPT. `gdisk` is one of several tools that handle GPT tables, and it will attempt to convert on start up. The conversion is done in memory only until you hit `w`. This would often fail if you hadn't just expanded the disk, but you have so it should work (GPT requires some sectors at the end of the disk as well as beginning; DOS MBR did not need the end).

When you fire up gdisk, you should see something like this:

```
***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

and you can use the normal commands you should be familiar with from fdisk to manipulate the GPT partition table.

Obviously, you should have backups in place, at very minimum your server team should snapshot your VM.

Long-term, you ought to consider using non-partitioned devices where possible, maybe through LVM. Then extending them is much easier and generally an online operation (for example, if you gave an unpartitioned device to LVM, it'd be a simple `pvresize /dev/whatever`, which takes a fraction of a second and is done online).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This does make since to me.  Between this and K7AAY answers, this gives me enough info to at least now go and research what I need to do.

Comment: Question:

How would I know if my drive is LVM?  I see that I have under my i guess /dev/sda that /dev/sda5 is LVM.  I still have the 10tb of space unassigned waiting, but how can i easily extend it with LVM or am I just confusing what you said?

Comment: @CedricGaines If `lvs` or `pvs` list logical/physical volumes, then you're probably using LVM. If they list nothing, then you're probably not.

Comment: Great the LVS and PVS worked.  Is there a good tutorial I can use that outlines how to create and expand the 10tb of unused space I have in /sda/dev to be utilized.  I know this newbish so please forgive me.  Also, i have backups, but if I have to use this 10tb of space, will that destory / format the data that already here?

Comment: @CedricGaines The 10TB of new space presumably is unused/empty/junk (so what happens to data on that new 10TB doesn't matter, but if there were data there, it'll probably be lost). The existing date in the VM should survive. Since you're on Ubuntu, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm is a good place to start (but make sure not to `pvcreate` a partition when you have data). Plopping "LVM" into Google found me a lot of introductions as well. Some of them are a bit newer than the Ubuntu wiki. Arch as normal has a bunch of stuff too https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM but less beginner.

Comment: @CedricGaines and RedHat makes some pretty comprehensive sysadmin documentation available, e.g., https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/index

Comment: this makes sense to some degree, but...  Question: When I run fdisk -l I can see that I have 10tb of disk there in /dev/sda.   So do I have to first create a volume from that 10tb before I can extend the lvm i want to make larger?

Comment: @CedricGaines Unless the entire disk is already an LVM PV (without a partition table), then you probably need to either extend the existing partition or create another partition to use the unallocated space. Which it sounds like you were in the process of doing when you asked your question. After resizing the partition, you likely have to reboot and then run `pvresize` on it. (if you used the whole disk for a LVM PV, without a partition table, you'd just have to run `pvresize`, and no reboot would be required). If you create a new partition, you'd pvcreate and vgadd it.

Comment: Ok, the admins added 10tb to the VM which when rebooted the 10tb showed up.  I do see 2 lvm's in the system which make up a total of 1.5tb (one lvm is 1tb the other is 500gb).  These were created using fdisk.  Since I can't use fdisk to create the new 10tb disk... 1.) is this where i would use gparted or is it parted to create the new 10tb disk casue it over 2tb?  2.) Would I be able to extend the 500gb lvm (made with fdisk) to now be 10.5tb with the new 10tb disk created in parted or gparted? and 3.) kind of the same as question 2, can mbr and parted disk work together?

Comment: Again, thank you so much with your answers.  Believe me its helping.  I work with developers that are mostly .NET and Windows admins and coders and I'm the only one with Linux knowledge (i develop in linux, but really hadn't had to deal with the true adminstration of linux.  So this is kinda new for me on this side of the wall.

Comment: @CedricGaines I'd first ask your storage admins if they can just add the new space as a new virtual disk; probably they can, avoiding the need to touch the old disk. Then you can use the entire new disk as an LVM PV. Otherwise, you'd need to convert the disk to gpt (which `gdisk` will do for you, if possible) and then just create a third partition. You get a lot of partitions with GPT — there isn't a tiny 4-partition limit.

Comment: I thought of that, but the server this is running on is a server running a Docker Elasticsearch cluster.  So the space its using is within the partition that was origianlly setup for it (1tb).  Now I'm expanding the drive to make it larger so that elastic will have plenty of space to grow.  So thats why i'm having to expand this original drive to include more space.  A new disk won't be able to expand this original drive... or could it?

Comment: so basically first step is to convert the /sda/dev disk to gpt? then extend and such with gdisk

Comment: @CedricGaines correct. gdisk will do the conversion when you start it, but not write it to disk until you write. You can go ahead and create the new partition (or extend an existing, by carefully deleting and recreating) before writing.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I get this 10 TB of space added to the server?

[gdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/gdisk.8.html) is an Ubuntu tool which gives you the ability to expand your partition.

> 2)  If I set up this partition using something other than fdisk, can I 
>   later expand my main drive with this space since it wasn't setup in
>   fdisk?

As the Man said, Yes, You Can. The tool originally used does not restrict you from using other tools. You might consider use of [LVM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lvm.8.html) because it's easier to adjust your partitions as things change.